# Reading multiple image using fileReader

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make the image as a input file button. Once image selected then the default image change to the image selected. 
By using the `fileReader` I am only able to target one image.

- How could I make it only target the `image` attr in that selected `div`?
- Is that possible ?

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="prep">
<div class="row">
    <label>Step 1</label>
    <img src="http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/129/soft_scraps/256/button_upload_01.png" id="upfile1" style="cursor:pointer" class="img"/ >
    <input type="file" class="inputimg" />
</div>
</div>
    <span class="add">Add Step</span>
```

**JS Code.**

```
$(document).on("click" ,".img" , function(){

$(this).closest("div").find(".inputimg").trigger("click");
});

var count = 1;
$(".add").on("click",function(){
    count ++;
var row = '<div class="row"><label>Step '+count+'</label><img src="http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/129/soft_scraps/256/button_upload_01.png" id="upfile1" style="cursor:pointer" class="img"/ ><input type="file" class="inputimg" />';
$(".prep").append(row);
});
    $(".inputimg").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });

function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('.img').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

refer to my [jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2h7ty/)

- Why the dynamically added image , the alignment is not same with the first one ?

Thank You

Comment: Adding a space after the `label` tag and before the `img` tag resolves the issue. I've updated your fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is obviously possible you just have to traverse the DOM in the proper hierarchy.

You need to make two changes.

1. Bind the change event to the newly dynamically created element too. 
   You can simply achive it by adding the following code after the 
   `$(".prep").append(row);` statement

   ```
       $(".inputimg").change(function () {
                readURL(this);
       });
   ```
2. In `realURL()` function you will have to be more specific as
   selecting like this `$('.img')` will select all the image tags and
   not just the one near to the clicked object.   So that part can be
   changed to `$(input).siblings('.img').attr('src',
   e.target.result);`

Have a look at the [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2h7ty/8/)

**Update 1:**

For your last question i.e. about the misalignment of the images, as mentioned by @rageit in the comment you need to add an extra space in between the `<label>` and `<img>` tag in your dynamically created elements, the updated fiddle reflects that.

Comment: Thank You ! I have try using $(this).closest(".img") to target the image but it doesn't work. why parent > children only it will target ? :)

Comment: @user3732837: `.closest` actually traverses up the DOM tree and tries to find the element. So it will happen something like, the element will check the criteria for itself, then move to the parent and find for .img and so on till it reaches the top of the DOM tree. But you need to find `.img` element that is on the same level. So you can also use the the `.siblings()` function.

Comment: @Shiva
R you there?

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide: yes I am.

Comment: @Shiva
i wanna ask that how we can restrict the number of steps in your fiddle?
Means what if i want to restrict user to maximum step 5. On further clicking user will find a dialog saying you can only create 5 steps.
Hope you understand what i mean to say.
..
I will upvote for you

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide: If I got your question right, You can have an if statement inside the `$('.add')` event listener and check the value of `count` variable. I have created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2h7ty/16/ please let me know if you needed something else.

Comment: @Shiva
Yes!
Exactly! I was looking for.
God Bless you !